# Amplify S3 Documentation "Using Amazon S3" - How to update Auth_Role policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm trying to understand the AWS Amplify documentation section "[Using Amazon S3](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js/#using-amazon-s3)". It says:

> If you set up your Cognito resources manually, the roles will need to be given permission to access the S3 bucket.

> There are two roles created by Cognito: an `Auth_Role` that grants signed-in-user-level bucket access and an `Unauth_Role` that allows unauthenticated access to resources. Attach the corresponding policies to each role for proper S3 access. Replace {enter bucket name} with the correct S3 bucket.

And then the docs provide JSON examples of Policies for `Auth_Role` and `Unauth_Role`. What's confusing me is that when I go into my Roles in my IAM console, I have the following:

- amplify--dev-153155-authRole (contains AppSync resources)
- amplify--dev-153155-authRole-idp (log group resources)
- amplify--dev-153155-unauthRole (empty)

Neither of which contain anything like the JSON examples. The "...authRole" Policy contains actions/resources concerning AppSync, but nothing to do with S3. Likewise for the other two. I expected to find permissions to allow my Amplify app to get/store S3 items, otherwise how is it able to currently do it?

So my questions are:

1. How do I create and attach the policies provided in the above documentation? Do I simply paste the JSON into new policies in my IAM console, and attach them to the `Auth_Role`?
2. Where are the default permissions stored? I have set up an amplify app and added S3 with `amplify add storage`. I can connect to the S3 bucket to add and retrieve files - so presumably there must be existing Polices. But my `Auth_Role` contains no Policies that reference S3?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_rw-bucket.html Did you have a look at this for S3 permissions?

Comment: And this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html?tag=mochaglobal10-20

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to some of this. Reading your first link - my guess/understanding of the instructions is that the JSON Policy provided can be attached to another resource (ie my Amplify app) to permit my Amplify app to perform actions on the S3 bucket. But if this is the case, why can't I find reference to any policies in my IAM console relating to Actions (ie "s3:*")? My Amplify app shouldn't be able to access the S3 bucket unless it has IAM permissions - or have I got that wrong?

Comment: Did you create the IAM user or your client? Your IAM user might not have the relevant permissions

Comment: https://www.hava.io/blog/aws-iam-policies-and-policy-structure
https://spacelift.io/blog/iam-policy
You can refer to these